# Privacy error page in Chrome not loading content scripts

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When accessing https sites in Chrome, if the sites have certificate issue, Chrome will show "Privacy error" page, as below:

[image]

I notice in this page, content scripts of my extension are not loaded.

Is it possible to let content scripts loaded in this page?

Comment: No. It's a built-in UI displayed via data: URL.

Comment: It'll be possible once https://crbug.com/55084 is fixed via https://crrev.com/c/968681

Comment: @wOxxOm Very helpful link. But I see in the thread chrome://* URLs are not effected by this bug: *"I think that data: URLs are fine and about:blank is fine, but I think we can't do it for all other about: pages since those have similar issues to chrome: pages."*

Comment: Why "but"? Of course those aren't affected, being a built-in browser UI.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't see the "Privacy error" page will be effected either...

Comment: Indeed, I'm wrong apparently, since Chrome never allowed extensions to modify its built-in pages.